# Is there a way to show pop-up infowindow for every new point in torque map without clicking or hovering on it?

Tags: carto

Trying to work with torque map, but I want to show a small story behind every point...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the new Odyssey.js library, which lets you do what you are talking about.

http://cartodb.github.io/odyssey.js

[Torque example](http://cartodb.github.io/odyssey.js/sandbox/sandbox.html#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)